# Page Library - new column with required field, how to prevent page creation if required field not filled

Tags: column, library, modern-experience, modern-pages, sitepages

Here's my problem:
In my default page library I have added the column "Content type". This contains a selection list (manual, source code, etc.) and can be edited via drop-down menu. I have set this field as a required field. Now when I create a page (start->"New menu"->page) and open the page properties, I see that my field is a required field - there is a small asterisk after the name and it is written in red. If I do not fill this field, I can still save the page. How can I prevent this? Users are required to fill in this field, how can I ensure that?

Comment: You have added modern-experience tag to your question. So just to clarify some doubts, Are you using SharePoint Online and "Site Pages" library? Are you creating a Modern Page (Site Page)? Is your "Content type" field is normal choice field? or you have added any custom content type to your library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **by design** in SharePoint Online Modern experience.

The list items/library files with incomplete/missing information will be shown in separate view called **Items/Files that need attention** like below:

[image]

Also it will show small message of **Required info** in column in list view (see in above image).

**Workarounds**:

1. Set **Default value** to your "Content Type" column from column settings.
2. **Use Approvals in SharePoint** - You can approve the site pages only after all information is filled for the newly created pages.

**Update**:

**Setting default value to column**:

1. Go to Site Pages --> Library settings.
2. Navigate to **Columns** section and click on the column name "Content Type".
3. Scroll down to **Default Value** and set one of the choices in textbox below it.
4. Click **OK**.

[image]

**Default Value Set automatically to Newly created Page**:

[image]

**In Site Pages Library**:

[image]

Comment: When I configure a column with a default value, the column is not filled automatically. On the page under page properties the property is not filled. When I save the page it is not present in the column. It is empty.

Comment: How you are setting default value of the column? check updated answer for setting default value

Comment: I have set it up exactly as shown. When I create a new page and open the page properties, this value is empty and not filled with the default value. When I save / publish the page, the column remains empty.

Comment: Strange. I am doing same and it is working perfectly fine for me. Can you check the choice option is exactly same (spelling and case) as default value?

Comment: Also, are you using modern experience? what do you mean by "page properties" after opening the page? Are you talking about the "Page Details" shown on modern pages when you open the newly created page or something else?

Comment: I'm using modern experience. I use the German language version, so please excuse the incorrect / unspecific translations on my part. By "page properties" I mean the section, which opens when I click on the button with the gear wheel on the editing page - I think "Page Details".

Comment: I am doing the same and it is working for me...Also you can try creating a microsoft flow/power automate on item/page creation event in library and check if the Content Type field is filled or not. If it is not filled then you can notify the end user to fill it. Once user fills all details then you can approve the page.

Comment: Have you managed to do it? Are you facing any issue in this workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work. The default value is not set... Notifying users is a good idea, but it does not prevent you from creating pages with an empty required field.

Comment: This is how it is in modern experience. It does not prevent users from creating pages without filling required field.

Comment: Then the naming **required** is chosen very badly.

Comment: You can create a new suggestion/idea on [SharePoint UserVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/) to improve SharePoint functionalities.

Comment: Can you please try creating a new field and set its default value and then add this field to your **Site Page** content type.

Comment: I dont know what do you exactly mean... Can you give me please an step by step instructions? Thank you :)

Comment: Create a new column in Site pages library, name it (TestContentType) --> set it as a required field --> Set default value to one of the choices --> make sure you have checked "Add to all content types" checkmark on create column page --> click OK.

Comment: Then try creating a new Site Page..once site page is created then publish it --> Click on "Page Details". You should be able to see the default value set in TestContentType column.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new column and setting default value??

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question, I don't know if there is another OOTB solution for it.

But i recommend you to work with SharePoint Approvals, don"t approve the site pages until the required information are filled.

Comment: If I want to allow pages to use the "request approval" function only when certain columns are filled, how do I notify the user? The user has to get a feedback if he requests approval for a page and some columns are not filled yet. I can notify him by e-mail, but is there a faster way to notify him?

Comment: You can work with Power Automate, If yes, then the answer to your question is YES, there is a faster way to notify him by using Power Automate notification actions

Comment: check this out, you can begin from the simple one https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/modern-approvals

Answer (score 0):

I have this before and solved by:

1. Create site column and make it required
2. Add the site column to content type
3. Add the content type to the page library

Hope this will help

Answer (score -2):

This is how it is... 
You cant prevent users from saving/publishing pages with an empty required field.
But you can vote for this feature: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/39672985-prevent-saving-of-site-pages-if-a-required-field-i