# Sharepoint - Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, metadata, file

I am looking for a similar windows which will pop in when uploading the document to a SharePoint online site "Modern Look".

I am able to get this window in SharePoint classic library when uploading a document.

But when I change the look to modern look it directly uploads the document instead of asking me for this window.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a default behavior in SharePoint Online modern experience.

There is no OOTB way to show the properties pop-up while uploading documents as of now.

However, the list items/library files with incomplete/missing information will be shown in separate view called Items/Files that need attention like below:

[image]

Also it will show small message of Required info in column in list view (see in above image).

You can read more about this in my answer at: [Page Library - new column with required field, how to prevent page creation if required field not filled](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/275528/page-library-new-column-with-required-field-how-to-prevent-page-creation-if-r/275582#275582)

---

**Additional**: Microsoft is adding similar experience for SharePoint Pages library, you can check it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=SharePoint&searchterms=63257). It says:

> A pre-publish panel enforces that authors supply missing required properties before they can publish a page or a news post. Additional improvements related to required properties in the pages library take effect.

I am not sure if Microsoft is planning to add this functionality for normal lists/libraries as well. If you want Microsoft to implement this then you can create a new idea at [SharePoint UserVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is no OOB way to re-build the similar pop-up window in SharePoint modern experience.

You can set columns to be required, still users can upload it without any trouble. And we will have file needs attention view. Here is a blog with more information about similar topic:https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-make-sharepoint-metadata-columns-required/

As I did not find any similar [UserVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/) post, you may need to create a new one by your own.

Answer (score 0):

As already indicated this is not possible OOTB. You should perhaps re-consider the use of metadata if you also plan to use OneDrive for Business because that currently also does not support metadata.

If you do want to use metadata then then only way forward is to use 3rd party apps. There are several tools out there that can show a "metedata" window when uploading documents. For example [here](https://www.slimapplications.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/ExplorerEmailMetadataFields.png).

To summarize:

1. Stick with classic view. Most likely not an option
2. Use modern view and train users to add metadata at a later stage.
3. Use 3rd party apps
4. Move away from using metadata

Paul