How to make choice column required?
I have created a new choice column for a document library.
I have selected YES for Require that this column contains information.
However, users can upload documents without the SharePoint forcing them to add the choice value. Shouldn't the SharePoint provide a popup immediately when file is being tried to be uploaded?

Check this thread: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/275528/page-library-new-column-with-required-field-how-to-prevent-page-creation-if-r/275582#275582. Let me know if it answers your question.

When uploading a file that has a Required Field Attributes, SharePoint does not block it if the Required Field is not filled in. It only highlights the required information.This is by design.

You can give suggestion in the feedback portal and help to make improvements. Many features of current products are designed and upgraded based on customers’ feedback.

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.
